# Line Breaks in plain text email views

Tags: php, html, laravel, email

I'm creating a view for plain text emails.. it has no PHP code in it (since it's just simple text), the contents of the view are only:

```
Hello {{$user}} \r\n
Welcome! \r\n
```

When I get read the e-mail, it shows:

```
Hello John \r\nWelcome! \r\n
```

How to make the newline character on plain text? (I'm on windows, sending e-mails through Laravel)

Comment: I guess the plain text version of e-mail only reads plain text, no html

Comment: try using `<?php echo PHP_EOL; ?>` instead of `\r\n`

Comment: Are you sure you send plain text email ? I mean is `Content-Type: text/plain;` specified ? In laravel 5.0 you should set the view of email as array with key 'text' like so `Mail::send(['text' => 'emails.view'] ...`